# SwiftUI stop Divider from expanding vertically in HStack

Tags: swiftui, hstack

I'm using SwiftUI to create something like an alert popup, which I present from UIKit code using UIHostingController. The view looks like this:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    // Some text ...   

    HStack(spacing:0) {
        Button(action: self.onCancel) { Text("Cancel") }
           .padding().inExpandingRectangle().fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

        // This divider is the problem
        Divider() // .fixedSize()

        Button(action: self.onDelete) {  Text("Delete") }
           .padding().inExpandingRectangle().fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}.frame(minHeight: 0)
```

The `inExpandingRectangle` is something I found in another stackoverflow question. It centers the text in each side of the HStack.

```
extension View {
    func inExpandingRectangle() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this. Garbage.

[image]

If I put the `.fixedSize()` on the divider, it does this. Not horrible, but the divider is stupid looking and doesn't expand to the size of the buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible simplified alternate, without that *artificial* extension. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
Divider() // or Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(height: 1)
HStack {
    Button(action: {}) { Text("Cancel").fixedSize() }
        .padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    Divider() // or Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(width: 1)

    Button(action: {}) {  Text("Delete").fixedSize() }
        .padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

}.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Note: It worth also to consider *custom* divider, like

```
Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(width: 1) // or any other color
```

than might give much appropriate visual feedback, like

[image: demo2]

Comment: It works, thank you. I hope someday we get an a detailed explanation of how SwiftUI layout really works. As it is, I just randomly try things and *hope* it works, which is not a fun way to write code.

Comment: @RobN Watch this, over and over: Stanford University's iOS class, lecture 5. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayQl_F_uMS4

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, I watched that video. It's very useful, but a big question for me remains: what exactly do they mean by "flexible"? They say the container offers the subviews space, in order of least to most flexible. But how is that flexibility defined? The view protocol has no `var flexibility: Double` property.

Comment: @RobN 

Layout Behavior 


1. Some views pull in to be as small as possible to fit their content. (I will refer to these as “pull-in” views.) For e.g Button Z/H/VStack, Text, etc.
2. Some views push out to fill all available space. (I will refer to these as “push-out” views.) Knowing these two behaviors can help you predict what will happen when using the different views. For e.g - Color

Answer (score 11):

Putting a `fixedSize()` modifier on the `HStack` instead of the `Divider` fixies the problem.

```
    var body : some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            // Some text ...
            Text("gsfdsfkajflkasdjflkas,jdflaskjf")
            HStack(spacing:0) {
                Button(action: {print("hi")}) { Text("Cancel") }
                    .padding().inExpandingRectangle().fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)

                // This divider is the problem
                Divider()


                Button(action: {print("hello")}) {  Text("Delete") }
                    .padding().inExpandingRectangle().fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            }.fixedSize()        <------- Insert this
        }.frame(minHeight: 0)
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I needed a slight variation: `.fixedWidth(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on the `HStack`, to keep the button text centered, but this answer helped.

Comment: I used `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code hope its help you (Xcode 11.2.1)

**Note**: Change `Font`, `Frame` and `Color` as per your requirement

```
var body: some View {

    VStack(spacing: 0) {

        Text("Delete")
            .font(Font.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))

        Text("Are you sure you want to delete ?")
            .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
            .padding([.top,.bottom], 15)

        Rectangle().fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.5)).frame(height:0.5)

        HStack(spacing:0) {

            Button(action: {
                //Your action
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .medium))
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 150, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .center)

            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.5)).frame(width:0.5,height:20)

            Button(action: {
                //Your action
            }) {
                Text("Delete")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 150, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]